# How do I preserve a UTF8 character set when doing an update into MySQL, from a Google Sheet?

Tags: mysql

I have an app to upload a spreadsheet into my MySQL database.  Some of the fields contain Unicode characters from Northwest Indian languages.  Example:

syəhúm tə nsná. nəsʔúŋəsteŋ c' cə yaʔ ʔaʔ kʷɬi čná ʔaʔ či himʔuyíca.

After the update, the MySQL table contains this:

sy?húm t? nsná. n?s?ú??ste? c` c? ya? ?a? k??i ?ná ?a? ?i him?uyíca.

If I enter the original directly into MySQL using MySQLAdmin or a similar tool, I have no such trouble, and doing a query to download the record back into google sheets is also successful.  It is just the upload that gives me fits.

Here is (more or less) the code snippet that pulls the cell into the update query:

```
var itm = sheet.getRange(rnum, 4).getValue();
var sql = "UPDATE dbo_accounts ";
sql += "SET item = '" + item + " ";
sql += "WHERE  history_id = " + hid;
SQLStatementE.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?  If you are using an earlier version than 8.0, you explicitly need to declare the character set for the column (or default character set for the table) to be utf8mb4.  What kind of client/connector are you using when it does not work?

Comment: MySqlAdmin shows this as mysql-5.5.51.

Comment: I think the server (at GoDaddy) is using mysql-5.5.51. The connector is jdbc.